# C/C++ How to format if conditions' single statement on the same line in VScode

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-code, formatting, code-formatting

If you don't use curly braces in C/C++ after declaring a condition, the body of the function becomes the next statement directly after; same thing for loops (while, for etc....).

I want the formatter to put this statement on the same line instead of the next line with an indent.

My code looks like this:

```
if (/*condition*/)
    /*body*/
```

I want it to look like this:

```
if (/*condition*/) body
```

Is there a way to format it in such a way? Note that this is **only** when not using curly braces, I'd still like for curly braces to work as normal i.e (on the next line).

Comment: Have you tried `clang-format` extension?

Comment: Don't do it. Your source becomes less readable. Adopt some common code style, don't invent your own.

Comment: @thebusybee I understand but it's just that if its one SINGLE statement like say if(something) break, it looks sooo ugly if it's just indented without the braces, and if i put the braces for just one line of code it feels super un-necissary, feels like bloat code lol, something like if(condition) break; looks miles prettier to me

Comment: @borygamer Actually you can use `clang-format` with `google` style to format your codes, which will give what you need as I tested.

Comment: @Bowen I'm kinda struggling on installing the extension that's why i didn't reply the first time, after installing and tried formatting it just says the command isn't available or something, anyways i figured the built in "C_Cpp.clang_format_fallbackStyle" setting should do the same job no ? i tried setting it to google and it does work but now the braces arent on the following line they are on the same line, also indents are wayyy smaller, basically i want Visual Studio style but with single line statements on a new line

Comment: sorry for being very picky about this 

Comment: I would also recommend against putting the body on the same line. In addition to being a questionable style, this prohibits to put a breakpoint on the body line. The day you want to check that the `if` condition is correctly taken, you will be unable to break on that condition without a recompilation (or looking at assembler level).

Comment: @borygamer With the extension, you need to at first install the executable which can be installed as a Python package. And with it, you're able to configure your own needs like the indentation width. I don't know what OS you are using but it should work in WSL and OSX. If you use OSX installation and usage should be straightforward. If you use windows, you can use it together with WSL extension. As for the situation with braces, they will be arranged to different lines if the configuration is correct as `google`, which at least is the case when I used `clang-format`.

Comment: @prapin hmmm didn't think of debugging, ill stick to visual studio for now

Comment: @Bowen i downloaded and installed it and it works yet the braces aren't formatted like id want them to.
i'll just stick to prapin and busybee's advice anyways, i haven't thought this through well